# Authentication using Linkedin app in Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, linkedin-api

I have been successfully using InAppBrowser method for Linkedin authentication in Cordova app (Ionic):

https://auth0.com/authenticate/phonegap/linkedin

https://github.com/YanchWare/SocialGap

However I want to "upgrade" this process to leverage the Linkedin app in the device itself (if installed). This should be similar to how to authenticate with Facebook: it will open the Facebook app without requiring user to login.

Is it possible to do something like that using Linkedin app?

Sorry for such a newbie question.